# Why do I get a SystemStackError when running `bundle install`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to setup my ruby environment, and I keep getting the following **`SystemStackError`** error message:

```
$ bundle install
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
Warning: No private key present, creating unsigned gem.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (11.1.2)
Using concurrent-ruby (1.1.3)
Using i18n (0.9.5)

SystemStackError: stack level too deep
An error occurred while installing multi_json (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install multi_json -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, multi_json v 1.5.0 is already installed:

```
$ gem list | grep multi_json
multi_json (1.5.0)
$
```

Any ideas how to get past this?

Comment: Have you tried removing multi_json from your Gemfile and trying again? Maybe uninstall multi_json and try again.

Comment: Yes, and that didn't do the trick.